# Forge BIM 360 Assets API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

is it planned to release a public API for the new BIM 360 module Assets? We would love to build an integration with this module.

If yes is this a near term project or a long term one?

Greetings,
Thomas

Comment: Dear Thomas, I have asked the development team for you (yesterday) and am waiting for an answer. I'll let you know as soon as I hear back from them.

Comment: @JeremyTammik Thanks very much for your help. I now got in touch with Mikako and we are on the way to finding out what we want to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas, hope is near future. We would be interested in hearing what you want to do with API.  It might help prioritizing. If you are willing to discuss and give us feedback, could you contact me at mikako.harada@autodesk.com ?